# How do I show only the unique topics?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unique

Right now I have this in my video show view:

```
<% @video.topics.each do |topic| %>
  <%= topic.name %>
<% end %>
```

Problem is that if a video has been associated with two of the same topics, it shows the topic twice. How can I fix this so that it only shows the unique topics?

Comment: Is the data considered valid when the video is associated to two topics?  Can you just write something on the write side to prevent dups?

Comment: yeah I have no validations yet... should I implement them for this? I don't want the user to encounter an error by adding a dup... just for it to fail silently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you should probably have some validations in your model(s) to prevent this from happening, you can call `#uniq` on the array of topics:

```
@video.topics.uniq.each do |topic|
```

Comment: yeah I have no validations yet... should I implement them for this or just use #uniq? I don't want the user to encounter an error by adding a dup... just for it to fail silently

Comment: @Justin: Add some validations and cleanups to your model, filtering with `uniq` is just covering up an underlying problem.

Comment: Yes, definitely add validations to your model! And if you really want this to "fail silently" for your users, just do a conditional on the database insertion... something like `@video.topics << topic unless @video.topics.include?(topic)` -- that way they think it worked, and you can avoid the duplicate database entry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use group to group the results by topic. This can be done either with find.group or by the Ruby group_by command. I think that should work for you.